# While Loop in SQL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in understanding why is the loop below not working. It only inserts the first record it then stops.

```
DECLARE 
@NEW_BALANCE            FLOAT
, @CUR_NEW_BALANCE      FLOAT
, @OLD_BALANCE          FLOAT
, @CUR_OLD_BALANCE      FLOAT
, @INITIAL_BALANCE      FLOAT
, @RATE                 FLOAT
, @MONTHLY_RATE         FLOAT
, @MONTHLY_INTEREST     FLOAT
, @PAYMENT              FLOAT



SELECT @RATE    = INTEREST
    FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ACCOUNT = 'AMEXDELTA'

SET @MONTHLY_RATE               = (@RATE / 12) / 100

SELECT TOP 1 @CUR_NEW_BALANCE       = NEW_BALANCE
             , @CUR_OLD_BALANCE     = OLD_BALANCE
FROM PAYMENTS ORDER BY ID DESC

SELECT @CUR_NEW_BALANCE AS NEW_BALANCE
       , @CUR_OLD_BALANCE AS OLD_BALANCE

WHILE @NEW_BALANCE > 0
BEGIN

    SET @MONTHLY_INTEREST               = (@CUR_OLD_BALANCE * @MONTHLY_RATE)

    SET @OLD_BALANCE                    = (@CUR_NEW_BALANCE - @PAYMENT)

    SET @NEW_BALANCE                    = (@MONTHLY_INTEREST + @OLD_BALANCE)


    INSERT INTO PAYMENTS(PAYMENT, MONTHLY_INTEREST, OLD_BALANCE, NEW_BALANCE)
        SELECT @PAYMENT, @MONTHLY_INTEREST, @OLD_BALANCE, @NEW_BALANCE


END
```

Below is the current data in the table PAYMENTS:

```
Old_Balance | New_Balance
------------|------------
2845.8      | 2845.8
```

Below is the current date in table ACCOUNTS

```
Interest
--------
15.24
```

Comment: @MartinSmith I put it back. I didn't want to post without thoroughly checking. After re-reading, I didn't understand why it even worked the first time... so I pulled it back.

Comment: @CJBS Yes the question must be wrong. The while is never true. So it is executed 0 times not 1.

Comment: I remove the loop and I'm still getting null values for old_balance and new balance

Comment: You never initialise @payment either.

Comment: @jorame - I suggest doing a bit more debugging, either in the IDE, or by using some PRINT statements to output the value of your variables at different stages of execution. Most likely the other problems are also related to variable-initialization. Float variables in T-SQL aren't auto-initialized to 0 as they might be in C#.

Comment: I have initialized all my variables and still get the same results. Let me do some more debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`@NEW_BALANCE` hasn't been initialized. It's NULL, which is not greater than 0 (it's undefined).

```
DECLARE 
@NEW_BALANCE            FLOAT

Select @NEW_BALANCE
```

Output:

```
----------------------
NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

So, initialize it:

```
DECLARE 
@NEW_BALANCE            FLOAT = 0

Select @NEW_BALANCE
```

Comment: The problem is that it was inserting one record before I initialized it. I did as you have suggested and still the same issue. I get one record with NULL values in Old_Balance and New_Balance fields in the Payments table.

Comment: Might be a problem with the overall code logic. Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx for some examples...